# How to filter the documents with nested objects whose values are stringified objects in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to filter only those ids whose nested objects has `tyre: MRF` present in it.
Consider the below schema, I have multiple such documents in a collection and I want to filter only those documents who has `tyre:MRF` under `data` in `accessories`.
**NOTE: values for `data` is stringified object**

```
{
_id : '1'.
accessories : {data : "{\"tyre\":\"MRF\",\"speakers\":\"bose\"}"}
},
{
_id : '2'.
accessories : {model: "{}"}
}
{
_id : '3'.
accessories : {data : "{\"tyre\":\"APOLLO\",\"speakers\":\"JBL\"}"}
}
```

Comment: you can use [$regex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)  but im not sure if it will work as expected in all conditions [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ZeYj39m_9s)

Answer (score 0):

With aggregation query, you can use [`$function`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator to parse the stringified value to JSON object (`accessories.dataObj`) with the JavaScript function. Next filter the result with `"accessories.dataObj.tyre": "MRF"`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "accessories.dataObj": {
        $function: {
          "body": "function (data) { return JSON.parse(data); }",
          "args": [
            "$accessories.data"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "accessories.dataObj.tyre": "MRF"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "accessories.dataObj"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KX_D-BpC0sc)